# Where to find iOS platform versions?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I've made about 12 Android apps, and I'm going to begin to start porting them over to iOS. One thing I always do before starting an application on Android is choosing a minimum API level. I usually use: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html and the pie chart provided to decide which specific levels I'm going to support. I've signed up for a iOS Dev Center account, but I don't see anything like this (distribution of iOS versions). I thought maybe joining the paid iOS Developer Program may enable me to see this information, but as of right now the site is down and I cannot register as a developer. Is there any easy way to find this? I'm not completely familiar with iOS so I don't want to make a decision out of the blue.

Comment: Here are some data: http://appleinsider.com/articles/13/06/06/ahead-of-ios-7-reveal-apples-ios-6-is-on-93-of-iphones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a graph on https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/checklist/ that claims that, as of June 29, 2013, 94% of users were on iOS 6, and another 5% on iOS 5.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. How did you find that link from the devcenter?

Comment: Clicked around on the public site a bunch! No real trick to it.

Answer (score 1):

As has been noted and sourced by others, iOS adoption rates are very swift compared to Android. By supporting one or two versions back, you will hit nearly all of the iOS market.

That being said, iOS 7 is different enough from previous versions that there is some additional overhead to support older versions. If you have the resources to support both 7 and 6, that is what I would recommend.

I would *not* recommend building new applications against the iOS 6 SDK at this time. Such applications will have the "classic" look on iOS 7 and will immediately look out of date.

To support the new look, you will need to build against the iOS 7 SDK. I believe access to the beta requires a paid account. You could, however, make significant headway with the iOS 6 SDK now and complete native iOS 7 support once registration opens up again.

Answer (score 0):

More than 90% iOS users have 6.x right now in their devices:

[Source 1](http://iflowreader.com/3432/news/apples-ios-6-runs-on-more-than-90-of-iphones/) - [Source 2](http://appleinsider.com/articles/13/06/06/ahead-of-ios-7-reveal-apples-ios-6-is-on-93-of-iphones) - [Source 3](http://www.weareapps.com/blog/90-of-iphone-and-ipad-users-now-running-ios-6/)

However, iOS 7 is around the corner, so you should consider to support both, iOS 6 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out http://iossupportmatrix.com/ ans conclude that in practical scenario you should start with ios 5 minimum.